# If someone knows my bitcoin address, does this mean they can spend it or move it?

Tags: address, security

What if I wrote down or saved a file with the address on and someone found it, can they take my coins?
How secure is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. An address is designed to be given out so that people can send you money. You cannot spend Bitcoin by knowing an address, otherwise block explorers wouldn't be showing people's addresses. What is needed to spend Bitcoin are private keys. Those need to be kept secret and are never given out to anyone. One private key corresponds to one address.

Answer (score 3):

See it this way: your address is similar to your email address. people use it to send you emails but only your email and password pair can access you inbox. Passwords are like your private keys.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a good way to think of it - email.

Consider your email address - anyone who knows it can send YOU an email.

But without knowing your password, nobody can use your email address to send SOMEONE ELSE an email.

Your bitcoin private key is critical to protect, much like your email passwords.